# How to record Script and keywordTest in Testcomplete together?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, functional-testing, testcomplete

My question is, Can TestComplete record script and keywordTest together? Because when I test my application, it either record script or keywordTest but not both in parallel. How Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch between keyword test recording and script recording on the fly by clicking the corresponding test type on the Recording toolbar:

[image]

(Image taken from http://www.automatedqa.com/products/testcomplete/record-playback/.)

> Can we record both types in parallel? i.e when it records KeywordTest it also record the corresponding script.

No, this is not possible. You can, however, manually [convert](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/keyword-testing/converting-script.html) the recorded keyword test into its script equivalent.

Comment: @Helen: This is switching. But as I mentioned that Can we record both types in parallel? i.e when it records KeywordTest it also record the corresponding script.

Comment: @Helen: Thanks. Can you please tell me how can I convert KeywordTest into Script?? I mean does TestComplete Provide this functionality??

Comment: @Ali: Right-click the test in the Project Explorer > Convert to Script. Follow the link in my answer for details.

Comment: @Helen: I think this feature is only available in TestComplete 8. It is not available in TestComplete 7. I looked for it everywhere but did not find anything. Correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: @Ali: Yes, you're right. TC7 doesn't have the test conversion feature.

Comment: @Helen: Thanks for your Comments and post. These are really helpful.